# Splitting chunks - problem with regex (js)?

Tags: regex, reactjs, webpack, webpack-splitchunks, splitchunksplugin

I'm trying to split my build files in my `webpack.config.js` file, but my `vendors`  file isn't being created at all. The remaining `node_modules`, which aren't `react` or `moment` files end up in the `main.js`. An example of a file that goes in `main.js` is `./node_modules/es-abstract`. I put in my regex and filename in a regex checker, and it passes the test. I'm not sure what's going on; any help would be greatly appreciated it.

```
splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        moment: {
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]((moment).*)[\\/]/,
          name: 'moment',
          chunks: 'all'
        },
        react: {
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]((react).*)[\\/]/,
          name: 'react',
          chunks: 'all'
        },
        vendors: { 
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]((?!(moment|react)).*)[\\/]/, 
          name: 'vendors', 
          chunks: 'all' 
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [David Gilbertson](https://hackernoon.com/the-100-correct-way-to-split-your-chunks-with-webpack-f8a9df5b7758), SplitChunks default settings only allows for three chunks. To solve this, these settings will need to be added to split chunks: `maxInitialRequests: Infinity,
      minSize: 0,`